# CSS DIV getting out of bounds

Tags: css, scroll, position

I'm trying to limit the scroll in http://www.liftdesignphoto.com/test/ because it gets the lift out of bounds.

Is there a way to recalculate the position so that it does not get out of bounds? (using % maybe).

Thanks

Comment: Interesting :) Since you're using JS anyway your best bet is to calculate the lifts position relative to the viewport depending on the  total wite height and minimum from the top and bottom... I'll mop something up later if someone else doesn't beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks folks for your kind help, i was close to throw in the towel.
I'm going to switch to absolute positioning to test. If you could help me with the JS to calculate the center of the screen it would be great

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the overflow you mentionned happens when it travels lower than level 0, you could, in your javascript, be able to implement a conditional check; if the lift is lower than the allowable minimum height (which you would need to measure yourself), don't animate it any further down (or simply animate if the scroll action event is downwards).

-- This is all relevant if your elevator doesn't have a position:fixed style, which I fear it has. My suggestion would be to switch to absolute positioning and have js code that will always center it to 50% of the screen, unless it hits top and bottom limits, in which case it will not raise any higher or lower than the limits that you set yourself in the code (see above). I would also suggest you use the jquery animate() function, updating the top or bottom attribute of the elevator in order to animate it on a scroll event (which you would need to detect if the scroll is going up or down) so that the movements will be more smooth.

All to say that it's impossible IMO to create position limits on a fixed positioned element as it's set above all other elements (thus not affected by sibling or ancestor position styling).

Hope this helps.

EDIT: another note on why not to use fixed positionning; when resizing the web browser, your life will behave erratically because it uses a fixed top-position (not even percentage-based value), it doesn't make for a very flexible interface.

Comment: I need to find the code to center the elevator 50% and it's done

Comment: A few suggestions (without looking at your js):
1- When redefining the position of your lift, i would call it within an animate() function call, so it would make the movement smoother (as simply defining the position straight to the attribute value will imitate the choppiness of browser scrolling.
2-Your level number on your lift isn't working as it was when the position was fixed, thought i'd point that out for you :)

Comment: 3-I think that when doing your checks for max and min vertical limits for your lift, you simply redefine your position or not (depending on the check's outcome). Although this might work for your browser in placing the lift at it's min and max height when the scroll is at the very top or bottom, but you need to try it in various browser dimensions and configuration. In my case, the lift never reaches the bottom and top. To counter this, i would make sure that when i check for min and max, if the lift hits these points, I'd set the lift position specifically to these heights vs. simply not...

Comment: ...defining a height. With the animate() function, this new check should work very smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I animated the changes and now it looks pretty smooth!
I'm detecting the top and bottom so that the lift never gets out of bounds. UPDATE: http://www.liftdesignphoto.com/testfinal/